# Calculate total number of matches played by team ,When it is present in both HomeTeam and Away Team col using pandas/pyspark

Tags: pandas, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Calculate the total number of matches played by teams, When it is present in both the `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` columns using pandas/pyspark.

I thought of using join. First, I `groupby()` the HomeTeam and get the result of the number of matches played by `HomeTeam` and same with `AwayTeam`. And then join them based on the team name.
I have attached the dataframe:
[image: 1]
Is there any better way to do it

Comment: Welcome STF. [Pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244910/how-to-pivot-spark-dataframe), maybe? also possible duplication of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49671240/10452700). Also, it would be nice when you post the question; please include what you have tried and provide **reproducible examples** and in the end, your expected output.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can *groupby* on both teams (and that fits your request: *"When it is present in both HomeTeam and Away Team"*):

```
df.groupBy("HomeTeam","AwayTeam").count().show(truncate=False)
```